# Agilent 33220A and Mathematica

Tags: driver

Searching an example of driving the Arbitrary wavegenerator Agilent 33220 A within Mathematica via the USB port

Comment: What is the OS of your machine ?

Comment: The operation system is Windows 7 Ultimate on a Dell M4300 portable. Windows 10 is also possible on a desktop, but then I loose flexibility, because Windows 10 cannot operate well on the Dell M4300.

Comment: @John Compter Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to drive some Keysight instruments from Mathematica on my MacBook Pro via the USB or ethernet port.